# Popular Post with wp_query and date_query wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a popular post section on my website to show the top 5 most popular posts of the past week.

Function for Popular Post

```
function shapeSpace_popular_posts($post_id) {
    $count_key = 'popular_posts';
    $count = get_post_meta($post_id, $count_key, true);
    if ($count < 1) {
        delete_post_meta($post_id, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($post_id, $count_key, '0');
    } else {
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($post_id, $count_key, $count);
    }
}
function shapeSpace_track_posts($post_id) {
    if (!is_single()) return;
    if (empty($post_id)) {
        global $post;
        $post_id = $post->ID;
    }
    shapeSpace_popular_posts($post_id);
}
add_action('wp_head', 'shapeSpace_track_posts');
```

Loop for the Popular Post

```
<?php $popular = new WP_Query(array(
                    'posts_per_page'=>5,
                    'date_query'          => array(
                        //set date ranges with strings!
                        'after' => '1 week ago',
                        'before' => 'today',
                        //allow exact matches to be returned
                        'inclusive'         => true,
                    ),
                    'meta_key'=>'popular_posts',
                    'orderby'=>'meta_value_num',
                    'order'=>'DESC'));
                    while ($popular->have_posts()) : $popular->the_post(); ?>
                    <h5 class="section_category">
                        <?php the_category(', ') ?>
                    </h5>
                    <div class="trending_title">
                        <?php the_title( sprintf( '<h4><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h4>' ); ?>
                    </div>
                    <h5 class="section_author">
                        By <?php coauthors_posts_links(); ?>
                    </h5>
                    <div class="border-bottom"></div>
                    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

If you can help in anyway I would be greatful.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

use "query_posts" instead of "WP_Query"

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'post',
    'showposts' => 5,
    'date_query'          => array(
        //set date ranges with strings!
        'after' => '1 week ago',
        'before' => 'today',
        //allow exact matches to be returned
        'inclusive'         => true,
    ),
    'meta_key' => 'popular_posts',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'   => 'DESC'
);
query_posts($args);
//query_posts('post_type=post&showposts=5&meta_key=popular_posts&orderby=meta_value_num&order=DESC');
if (have_posts()) : 
?>
<?php
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
?>
     <h5 class="section_category">
        <?php the_category(', ') ?>
    </h5>
     <div class="trending_title">
        <?php the_title( sprintf( '<h4><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h4>' ); ?>
    </div>
    <h5 class="section_author">
        By <?php coauthors_posts_links(); ?>
    </h5>
    <div class="border-bottom"></div>
<?php
endwhile; 
?>
<?php
endif;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: It doesnt seem to make a difference when I replace with this. Any suggestions why?

Comment: everything works great until the date_query then it seems to be unresponsive and I am unsure why

Comment: you can try 'column'  => 'post_date', 'after'   => '- 7 days', instead of  'after' => '1 week ago',